# Remove identifiers from object

Tags: javascript, object

i have a object which has identifiers:

```
const cities = {
  "0": {
    "city": "Bielsko-Biała",
    "country": "PL",
  },
  "1": {
    "city": "Kielce",
    "country": "PL",
  },
  "2": {
    "city": "Kłodzko",
    "country": "PL",
  }
}
```

What i want is to remove 0, 1, 2 and so on to get this format:

```
const cities = [
   {
    "city": "Bielsko-Biała",
    "country": "PL",
  },
 {
    "city": "Kielce",
    "country": "PL",
  },
  {
    "city": "Kłodzko",
    "country": "PL",
  }
]
```

It is neccessary to me because i want to add description to every city and i couldn't map in this object because of that format.

I had to do something like that in React and i think it is a very bad written code:

```
const cities = [];

countries.map(el => {
  cities.push(el.city)
})

let updatedCountries = countries;

cities.forEach((city) => {
  axios.get(`https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/${city}`)
    .then(response => {
      for (let property in updatedCountries) {
        if (updatedCountries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          if (updatedCountries[property].city === city) {
            updatedCountries[property]['description'] = response.data.description
          }
        }
      }
    })
})

this.setState({
  countries: updatedCountries
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

> The `Object.values()` method returns an `array` of a given object's own enumerable property values,

```js
const cities = {
  "0": {
    "city": "Bielsko-Biała",
    "country": "PL",
  },
  "1": {
    "city": "Kielce",
    "country": "PL",
  },
  "2": {
    "city": "Kłodzko",
    "country": "PL",
  }
}
let values = Object.values(cities);
console.log(values);
```